# Select and fill input value dynamically from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jquery code like this:

```
let $options = JSON.parse(data.options);
let $keys = Object.keys($options);
$keys.forEach(function (item,index, array) {
  $('#' + item ).val($options[item] );
});
```

I want to fill all input value in the id from the $keys with data in the $options. but it doesn't work. but if I do it manually like this it works:

```
      $("#title").val($options.title);
      $("#type").val($options.type);
      $("#location").val($options.location);
```

I'm sure that the problem is in the this code:  `$('#' + item )` i try so many things but seem it doesn't work. so is it any way i can fix this?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="widget_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddUserModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form id="widget_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/widgets/store">
            <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="csrf_token">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                        Add Widget
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="title">
                            Widget Title *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="type">
                            Type *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="custom-select form-control" id="type" name="type">
                                <option value="">Select Widget Type</option>
                                <option value="popular-post">Popular Post</option>
                                <option value="recent-post">Recent Post</option>
                                <option value="featured-post">Featured Post</option>
                                <option value="post-tabs">Post Tabs</option>
                                <option value="post-carousel">Post Carousel</option>
                                <option value="tags">Tags</option>
                                <option value="archive">Archive</option>
                                <option value="calender">Calendar</option>
                                <option value="blockquote">Blockquote</option>
                                <option value="mini-gallery">Mini Gallery</option>
                                <option value="list">List</option>
                                <option value="search">Search</option>
                                <option value="testimonials">Testimonial Carousel</option>
                                <option value="social-media">Social Media</option>
                                <option value="contact-us">Contact Us</option>
                                <option value="flickr">Flickr Feed</option>
                                <option value="instagram-feed">Instagram Feed</option>
                                <option value="recent-tweets">Recent Tweets</option>
                                <option value="video">Video</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="post_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="post_number">
                            Number of Post
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="post_number" name="post_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="testimonial_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="testimonial_number">
                            Number of Testimonial
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="testimonial_number" name="testimonial_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="galleries_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="image_number">
                            Number of Image
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="image_number" name="image_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="video_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="video_url">
                            Video URL
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="video_url" name="video_url" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blockquote_div">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="blockquote_author">
                                Author
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input id="blockquote_author" name="blockquote_author" class="form-control" autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="blockquote_content">
                                Quote
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input id="blockquote_content" name="blockquote_content" class="form-control" autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="location">
                            Location *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="custom-select form-control" id="location" name="location">
                                <option value="">Select Position</option>
                                    <option value="left">Left</option>
                                    <option value="right">Right</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my full edit script:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let $id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
            let url = "/admin/widgets/" + $id + "/edit";

            $.post(url,{ id: $id, csrf_token: $csrf }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.options);

                let $options = JSON.parse(data.options);

                var post = ["popular-post", "recent-post", "featured-post", "post-tabs","post-carousel"];

                if (post.includes($options.type)){
                    post_div.show();
                    testimonial_div.hide();
                    galleries_div.hide();
                    video_div.hide();
                    blockquote_div.hide();
                }else if($options.type === 'testimonials'){
                    post_div.hide();
                    testimonial_div.show();
                    galleries_div.hide();
                    video_div.hide();
                    blockquote_div.hide();
                }else if($options.type === 'mini-gallery'){
                    post_div.hide();
                    testimonial_div.hide();
                    galleries_div.show();
                    video_div.hide();
                    blockquote_div.hide();
                }else if($options.type === 'video'){
                    post_div.hide();
                    testimonial_div.hide();
                    galleries_div.hide();
                    video_div.show();
                    blockquote_div.hide();
                }else if($options.type === 'blockquote'){
                    post_div.hide();
                    testimonial_div.hide();
                    galleries_div.hide();
                    video_div.hide();
                    blockquote_div.show();
                }else{
                    post_div.hide();
                    testimonial_div.hide();
                    galleries_div.hide();
                    video_div.hide();
                    blockquote_div.hide();
                }

                page_modal.modal("show");

                let $keys = Object.keys($options);
                $keys.forEach(function (item,index, array) {
                    console.log($('#' + item));
                    $('form [name="' + item +'"]').val($options[item] );
                });

                validator.resetForm();
                $(".modal-title").text("Edit Widget");
                page_modal.find("form")[0].reset();
                $("#id").val(data.id);
                $("#csrf").val($csrf);
                submit_button.html("Update Widget");
            });
        });
```

Here's the screnshot that provided by   console.log('item : ' + item); and                    console.log('$options[item] =' + $options[item] );

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `data.options`? Also check the console for errors which will help you debug the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a json. like this: {"title":"Posts Tab","type":"post-tabs","post_number":"2","location":"right"}
widgets.js:308 {"title":"Testimonial Number","type":"testimonials","testimonial_number":"3","location":"right"}

Comment: i console for the error already. no error at all.

Comment: @Ying since the JSON object you've shared above is not an array, you can't iterate it with `forEach`. Try changing your `data.options` value into an array, even if it returns one value. Then you'll be able to perform `forEach` on that object.

Comment: Your posted code works. Error has to be in the data object https://jsfiddle.net/80wbkajy/2/

Comment: @Lapskaus i will try to lnspect it, i console log it and i have no problem, the item is same and the value is correct. not sure what's wrong with the data. but i will try to check it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just access them in jQuery using the name attribute of the form fields.
Assuming each option keyname is the same as the form field name of course.

By using brackets `[]` and then the attribute name and optionally an attribute value you can target specific elements with specific values.
For more reading choose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```js
+function() {
  let data = {
     options : '{"title":"Posts Tab","type":"post-tabs","post_number":"2","location":"right"}'   
  };
  let $options = JSON.parse(data.options);
  let $keys = Object.keys($options);
  $keys.forEach(function (item,index, array) {
    $('form [name="' + item +'"]').val($options[item] );
  })
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="widget_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AddUserModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form id="widget_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/widgets/store">
            <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="csrf_token">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                        Add Widget
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="title">
                            Widget Title *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="type">
                            Type *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="custom-select form-control" id="type" name="type">
                                <option value="">Select Widget Type</option>
                                <option value="popular-post">Popular Post</option>
                                <option value="recent-post">Recent Post</option>
                                <option value="featured-post">Featured Post</option>
                                <option value="post-tabs">Post Tabs</option>
                                <option value="post-carousel">Post Carousel</option>
                                <option value="tags">Tags</option>
                                <option value="archive">Archive</option>
                                <option value="calender">Calendar</option>
                                <option value="blockquote">Blockquote</option>
                                <option value="mini-gallery">Mini Gallery</option>
                                <option value="list">List</option>
                                <option value="search">Search</option>
                                <option value="testimonials">Testimonial Carousel</option>
                                <option value="social-media">Social Media</option>
                                <option value="contact-us">Contact Us</option>
                                <option value="flickr">Flickr Feed</option>
                                <option value="instagram-feed">Instagram Feed</option>
                                <option value="recent-tweets">Recent Tweets</option>
                                <option value="video">Video</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="post_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="post_number">
                            Number of Post
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="post_number" name="post_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="testimonial_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="testimonial_number">
                            Number of Testimonial
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="testimonial_number" name="testimonial_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="galleries_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="image_number">
                            Number of Image
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="image_number" name="image_number" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="video_div" class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="video_url">
                            Video URL
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input id="video_url" name="video_url" class="form-control" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blockquote_div">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="blockquote_author">
                                Author
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input id="blockquote_author" name="blockquote_author" class="form-control" autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="blockquote_content">
                                Quote
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input id="blockquote_content" name="blockquote_content" class="form-control" autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="location">
                            Location *
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select class="custom-select form-control" id="location" name="location">
                                <option value="">Select Position</option>
                                    <option value="left">Left</option>
                                    <option value="right">Right</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </button>
                    <button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. is it because it's inside a modal or something?

Comment: but when i fill the data like this it's work  $("#location").val($options.location);. Form input name is the same, but not sure why it's not filled with the data.

Comment: Your form fields don't have the attribute `id="location"` the [# stands for id selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors). Just make it like  `$('[name="location"]').val($options.location);` if you don't want the automated iteration. For clarity you could post the contents of `data.options` in your question.

Comment: It has. that why this code works: $("#location").val($options.location);.

Comment: @Ying, Please update your question with the rendered output of your form(right click inspect element, copy the form) Since my form example works(if you press run code snippet) and also post the contents of data.options.

Comment: @Ying My example also works with your posted options values in your form.What I think causes the problem are these lines of code: `validator.resetForm();
                $(".modal-title").text("Edit Widget");
                page_modal.find("form")[0].reset();` I suggest you move those **before** the forEach loop. Because these probably empty out your forms to defaults right after you set your values.

Comment: Thank you. Just let me know if you need me to try something. I really don't get it i don't think that my data will be wrong since the $key is extracting from $_POST key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206157/discussion-between-tschallacka-and-ying).